# Why does preg_match match multiple empty strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Why does the following regex:

```
$regex = '^([abc]+)$|^([012]+)$|^([23]+)$|^([123]+)$';
$toMatch = '123';
preg_match('/'.$regex.'/', $toMatch, $matches);
```

result in this result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

Why are the elements 1,2 and 3 empty strings while they didn't match anything? How come there are an "empty" matches?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your regex supposed to be matching?

Comment: I found this behavior while matching multiple pattern at the same time. I am trying to understand why those empty matches are happening.

Comment: What @anubhava is asking is what are your plain language rules for a *match*? You cant really expect anyone to debug a logical error without an explanation can you?

Comment: Doesn't it make sense though? Since you have 4 capture groups in your regex. So you have 3 empty ones, and the last one that matched it.

Comment: You are getting empty string in capture group # 1, 2, 3 because only 4th group is populating with `123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attempted to capture 4 different things with the `()` syntax.  Therefore, there will be 4 different elements in the `$matches` array.  Only the last capture will match the string `123` (`^[123]+$`).

See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving 3 empty elements because of your first three capture groups `([abc]+)`, `([012]+)` and `([23]+)` that did not match anything.

If you only want a single capture group, you could update your regex like this:

```
preg_match('/^([abc]+|[012]+|[23]+|[123]+)$/', '123', $match);
```

Which will give you:

```php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```